# Unable to run php commands in VPS

Tags: php

I have a PHP-FPM installed in a VPS. As a result, now I am unable to run some commands that depend on PHP like.

`php composer.phar update` or `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
And other commands related with PEAR. I keep adding "-fpm" at the end like this `php-fpm` but it won't work. I also tried to install as `yum install php` but, it conflicts with PHP-FPM it won't install.

Any ideas/solutions?

### EDIT

this is what I get when I run `yum install php-cli`

[image]
I have tried both suggestions mentioned at the bottom. But, still it does not install it.

Comment: it should report an error, what is the error? have you verified the file locations? if you do `/usr/bin/php` does it work then?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It says. `-Bash No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Try installing php-cli:

```
yum install php-cli
```

This should give you the command line PHP which you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not seem to work. I have added a snapshot of the result I got when I did `yum install php-cli`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but this finally did it.

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=remi install php-cli
```